# Object/Group Instances and Pass Index

Tags: render-passes, id-mask

For Post Production in the Compositor, I heavily rely on using Object/Material Index masks. Normally, I select a single object and then give it an unique number in the Pass Index/Material Index slider in the Object/Material tab. Using the ID mask node in the compositor usually gives a black/white image mask.

However, this doesn't seem to work on group instances. When grouping objects together and using the resulting instance, one can still give this object a Pass Index value. But the result isn't a black/white image, but rather a white/alpha file (but messed up), or the file is completely empty.
Giving the individual objects of an instance a Pass Index doesn't work as well when using the instance itself.

Is there a way to get the Pass Index on instances to work?

Comment: It seems to be possible with Pablo Vasquez Amaranth toolset : https://pablovazquez.art/amaranth/
(search "Object ID for Dupli Groups")

Comment: @thibsert Thank you very much, that worked like a charm! If you set this up as an answer, I could accept it as the right one.